# How to fix the jquery with ajax code localhost says object object error

Tags: jquery, ajax

When i call this jquery function with ajax getting [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jafjk.png)

> [object Object]

```
$('a#room_no').click(function() {
  var roomNumber = $(this).text();
  alert(roomNumber);
  var href = $(".room_check_out_form").attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: href,
    data: {
      roomNumber: roomNumber
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      alert(data.roomNumber)
    },
    error: function(err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: $('a#room_no').click(function() 
 {
   var roomNumber = $(this).text(); 
   alert(roomNumber);
    var href = $(".room_check_out_form").attr('href');
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: href,
     data: {roomNumber:roomNumber},
     dataType: "JSON",
     success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
     alert(data.roomNumber)
     },
     error: function(err) {
     alert(err);
     }
     }); 
 });

Comment: Use `console.log(...)` instead of `alert(...)` and let us know what you see instead. I'd imagine you're getting an error and falling to `alert(err)`, however `alert()` reveals no details about an object, whereas `console.log()` will.

Answer (score 1):

In your `error` handler, `err` is an object; the alert(err) is causing '[object Object]' to be shown in an alert dialog.

Changing your error handler to something like this should log more useful information to the console. Inspect the properties of the `err` object:

```
error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(err.responseText);
    alert(err.responseText);
}
```